# Chart display on button click in a pannel in jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

```
<h:form id="form" >
  <p:panel id="outPanel" widgetVar="outpanel" closable="true" toggleable="true" >                
    <p:commandButton update=":form" value="show Bar" onstart="this.disabled=true;$('#form\\:bar').show()" oncomplete="this.disabled=false; $('#form\\:line').hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="show Line" onstart="this.disabled=true; $('#form\\:line').show()" oncomplete="this.disabled=false; $('#form\\:bar').hide()"/>
    <p:chart id="bar"  type="bar" model="#{barChartBean.model}" style="height:160px;"/>                     
    <p:chart id="line" type="line" model="#{lineChartBean.model}" style="height:160px;"/>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Hi, using this code I have created two buttons to display two different images on the same location but when the page loads for the first time or gets refreshed both the images appear together whether I want one image at a time on button click ...not before that.

Comment: using this code I am trying to display 2 different charts on the same location on my web page

Comment: simplify yout problem. 1: is it related to chars? Try what happens with simple `h:inputtexts`. Is it related to a panel? Remove it and try. 3: Why do you update the full form on the button request? The hiding/showing gets lost then. Learn about the 'rendered' attribute of tags, and learn about 'ajax'

Comment: Its not related with charts...m able to display appropriate chart on button click but the problem is on loading/refreshing the web page both charts get appear on the page at the same time whether I want them on button click only

Comment: plzz guide me about rendered attribute if that can solve my problem.thanks in advance..

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials about the basics of this on the internet.